# get the package name of the application that is calling my app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-package-managers

I am developing an application in android that create folders and stored files and images in these folders. Each folder have a list that contains the name of applications that are permitted to access these files and image. my question is what is the code that can give me the package name of the application that is accessing my app in order to compare it with the names of apps in the list of each folder. I succeed in getting the package name when the case is that other application retrieve data from my application (startActivityForResult). but i cant get the package name when the case is just view (startActivity)!!! I need to know the package name in both case. any help?

Comment: You can't. It isn't possible to find out what application launched your Activity.

Comment: but the documentation of android says that i can get the application package Name accessing my app if and only if that app is accessing it to retrieve data ( which is by implementing startActivityForResult () ) . So how come retrieving the package name is feasible in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. That isn't possible.

When an Activity is started with `startActivityForResult()`, Android needs to know who to return the result to. It keeps this information in an internal data structure and makes the information available to the called Activity via `getCallingActivity()` and `getCallingPackage()`.

However, when an Activity is started with `startActivity()`, Android doesn't store the information about the caller Activity because it doesn't need this information (because Android knows that it isn't going to return a result to the caller Activity) and therefore it isn't available to your Activity.

Note that activities can also be started by Service and BroadcastReceiver component, so there isn't always a "caller Activity".

This is either a flaw in the design of Android or a "security feature", depending on how you want to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! Really Appreciate it! But i have one more question: what about the case of rooted android device? Is it possible to get the package name?

Comment: I don't see how rooting the device would make any difference. Android isn't keeping track of this information, so how would you get it?

Comment: What do you think the solution could be? Do you have any suggestions that can help me to replace the need of getting the package name in order to achieve the scope of the application? Thank you in advance.!

Comment: You could have the calling activity provide its package name in an `Intent` "extra"

Comment: Can I get the path of the folder that the other application want to access it?

Comment: How is the other application accessing the file/folder?

Comment: through the file path

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand what youwant to do

Comment: If another app opens a file directly using the file path, it can bypass your app completely. How is your app supposed to provide access control? Please explain the scenario.

Comment: i am saving those files with an invalid extension that only my app can open. therefore other app trying to access invalid extension are obliged to go through my app first. Once an other application access one of these folder i want to know which folder is been accessed in order to see if this application is permitted to access the files contained in the folder.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand your architecture. How does another application "access one of these folder"? Please post example code showing how another application is accessing the files/folders. This is hard to follow :-(